# Custom List View with thumbnail using Android Volley Library will not load any results

Tags: java, android, json, android-listview, android-volley

I am trying to load a custom listview using Volley Networking library but there are no results while running the app and no errors on the code. The data come from a JSON file

[JSON OUTPUT HERE](http://178.62.67.237/api/v1/residential/?format=json)

Below are my classes :

MainActivity.java

```
package info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley;

import info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.adater.CustomListAdapter;
import info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.app.AppController;
import info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.model.CaseStudy;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // Log tag
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    // Movies json url
    private static final String url = "http://178.62.67.237/api/v1/residential/?format=json";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<CaseStudy> caseList = new ArrayList<CaseStudy>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, caseList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();

        // changing action bar color
        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1b1b1b")));

        // Creating volley request obj
        JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();

                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                CaseStudy reference = new CaseStudy();
                                reference.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                                reference.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                                reference.setPostcode(obj.getString("postcode"));


                                // adding movie to movies array
                                caseList.add(reference);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        hidePDialog();

                    }
                });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

CaseStudy.java:

```
package info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.model;



public class CaseStudy {
    private String title;
    private String thumbnailUrl;
    private String postcode;

    public CaseStudy() {
    }

    public CaseStudy(String name, String thumbnailUrl, String postcode) {
        this.title = name;
        this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
        this.postcode = postcode;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String name) {
        this.title = name;
    }

    public String getThumbnailUrl() {
        return thumbnailUrl;
    }

    public void setThumbnailUrl(String thumbnailUrl) {
        this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
    }

    public void setPostcode(String postcode) {
        this.postcode =  postcode;
    }

    public String getPostcode() {
        return postcode;
    }



}
```

CustomListAdapter.java:

```
package info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.adater;

import info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.R;
import info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.app.AppController;
import info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.model.CaseStudy;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;

public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<CaseStudy> caseItems;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<CaseStudy> caseItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.caseItems = caseItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return caseItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return caseItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_custom, null);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView postcode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.postcode);
        //TextView genre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.genre);
        //TextView year = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.releaseYear);

        // getting movie data for the row
        CaseStudy c = caseItems.get(position);

        // thumbnail image
        thumbNail.setImageUrl(c.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);

        // title
        title.setText(c.getTitle());
        postcode.setText(c.getPostcode());      
        // rating
        //rating.setText("Rating: " + String.valueOf(m.getRating()));

        // genre
        //String genreStr = "";
        //for (String str : m.getGenre()) {
        //  genreStr += str + ", ";
        //}
        //genreStr = genreStr.length() > 0 ? genreStr.substring(0,
        //      genreStr.length() - 2) : genreStr;
        //genre.setText(genreStr);

        // release year
        //year.setText(String.valueOf(m.getYear()));

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

ist_row_custom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_row_selector"
    android:padding="8dp" >

    <!-- Thumbnail Image -->
    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

    <!--  Title -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textSize="@dimen/title"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <!-- Postcode-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/postcode"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textSize="@dimen/rating" />

    <!-- Genre -->

    <!-- Release Year -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any ideas what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring to wrong xml in you MainActivity. Kindly create a new xml for ex activity_main.xml and initiate your list view there.

Also in your code you are Calling JSONArray however your Json output shows it Json Object. Kindly change your code to JSONObject as shown below

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                hidePDialog();
                System.out.println("JsonObject++===---"+jsonObject);
                try {
                    JSONArray response = jsonObject.getJSONArray("objects");

                    for(int i=0; i <response.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        CaseStudy reference = new CaseStudy();
                        reference.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                        reference.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image_path"));
                        reference.setPostcode(obj.getString("postcode"));


                        // adding movie to movies array
                        caseList.add(reference);
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    System.out.println("error");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError arg0) {
                hidePDialog();
            }
        });
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest, TAG);
```

Comment: I have updated the answer, Kindly follow the answer you will get the output

Answer (score 1):

According to your Json you should get 'image_path' not 'image' .

```
     reference.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
```

use

```
    reference.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image_path"));
```

Comment: Well the manifest has Internet permission declared into it so that aspect is correct. Now i was trying to Log.d("Thumbnail", c,.getThumbnailUrl()); but nothing prints out on the logCat

Comment: There is something wrong with your json parsing . thats why it is null or empty .

Comment: According to your Json you should get 'image_path' not 'image' .

Comment: Hello Thanks for spotting this for me...I changed my code but still cannot get a result..There must be something else missing aswell!